# How can I workaround the XFCE4 power manager being broken?

Tags: xubuntu, power-management

I just did a clean install of 12.04 on my netbook, then installed xubuntu-desktop. (The reason for that is the showstopper bugs in 11.10 Unity -- like menus not working, or the launch bar capturing the mouse and locking up the machine)

Now, the power button does nothing.
Attempting to go to power settings from the xcfe4 settings times out.

I checked, and xfce4-power-manager is running, as well as /usr/lib/upowerd.

Trying

```
sudo xfce4-power-manager --dump
```

does nothing for a minute or so, then gives me the following message:

```
ce4-power-manager:4226): xfce4-power-manager-ERROR **: Did not receive a reply. 
Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message 
bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network 
connection was broken.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

along with the "crash" icon on the top panel, which I've now seen over 30 times in approximately 8 hours of uptime.

I'd be very interested in knowing how to get back up to the level of functionality that I had with 11.10 on this netbook.

Comment: This bug report on Xfce's site looks relevant: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8809
It's still open, but the bug reporter noticed that it might be some interference with the login screen and plugins managed by LightDM.

Comment: You can try installing the package xfce4-battery-plugin. It contains a battery indicator that is independent of Xfce Power Manager. Too bad I can't add this as an answer.

Comment: I had this problem, i unchecked "Power Manager" from "Application Autostart" list in `Settings -> Session and Startup` and added another application with this command `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon` then i have not have this problem yet.

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam Can you post your comment as an answer so we can mark this question as solved? thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro I did it.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem, i unchecked "Power Manager" from "Application Autostart" list in `Settings -> Session and Startup` and added another application with this command `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon` then i have not have this problem yet.

Comment: Thanks, this solved a similar problem for me on Lubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Additionally, xfce4-power-manager --customize does nothing for me.  Instead I need to use xfce4-power-manager-settings. (I'm using Xfce Power Manager 1.2.0 on  Ubuntu 14.04.1;   version 1.3.1, discussed at the end of https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8809, apparently fixes the bug that is the main subject of this question and for which --no-daemon is a workaround; but this fixed version  has not made into ubuntu 14.01 LTR, which continues to provide the buggy xfce4-power-manager.)