# sometimes xfce4-power-manager stuck

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

sometimes the xfce4-power-manager does not show up in the panel and it`s not working at all, and sometimes is working.

when it`s not working I have 2 solutions:

1. - log out, and log in.
2. - start system monitor and kill xfce4-power-manager, then start terminal and type:

   xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon

usually I use second solution, but to simplify the process I tried to write a shell script that restarts the xfce4-power-manager, with no success.

I cannot shut down the xfce4-power-manager from terminal.

```
xfce4-power-manager --restart
```

-is not working

```
xfce4-power-manager --quit
```

-is not working

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`pidof xfce4-power-manager`
kill $PID
xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon
```

-is not working.

If I type:

```
xfce4-power-manager --customize
```

-an error window appears with:

Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

in the system monitor at Waiting Chanel says: futex_wait_queue_me.

Thank you

Comment: I found an answer that may help, not tested yet:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/129671/how-can-i-workaround-the-xfce4-power-manager-being-broken?rq=1

 0 down vote
 

I had this problem, i unchecked "Power Manager" from "Application Autostart" list in Settings -> Session and Startup and added another application with this command xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon then i have not have this problem yet.

Answer (score -1):

xfce4-power-manager not started, applet not visible

Delete > Desktop configuration file:
/etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop

.

Settings Manager / Session and Startup / Startup Applications

Item disabled:
Energy Management (power Management Xfce environment)

New item enabled with new command:

Mame:          Xfce Power Manager (For example-Your name)

Description:   Power manager startup

Command:       xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon

http://ubuntuset.url.ph/power_manager.html