# xubuntu 13.10 xfce4-power-manager not working

Tags: xubuntu, xfce4-power-manager

I found that if `xfce4-power-manager` does not work if it is started with `/usr/bin/xfce4-power-manager`, the process is there but no power icon would be shown, the *Power Manager* in *Settings* does not work either.

However if I start xfce4-power-manager with command `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon` option, everything works normally. Is there anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: I have this problem as well.  I strace'd it, and it just hangs at a certain point.  This problem was not present in 13.04.

Comment: This looks relevant:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8809

Comment: I am running `xfpm 1.2.0` without major issues. Also check http://askubuntu.com/questions/129671/how-can-i-workaround-the-xfce4-power-manager-being-broken?rq=1 .

Answer (score 1):

xfce4-power-manager not started, applet not visible

Delete > Desktop configuration file:

/etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop

Settings Manager / Session and Startup / Startup Applications

Item disabled:

Energy Management (power Management Xfce environment)

New item enabled:

```
Name:             Xfce Power Manager (for example your name)
Description:      Power manager startup
New command:      xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon
```

http://ubuntuset.url.ph/power_manager.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a launcher by the following method.
Copy and paste the code in gedit and do the required changes..

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Power Manager
Comment=
Exec=/usr/bin/xfce4-power-manager
Icon=[link to icon(not required)]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=[choose what categories you want this file]
```

and save the file as **anyname.desktop**

For more info on [how to create a launcher visit -> Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330781/how-to-create-launcher-for-application)