# xfce4-power-manager does not open

Tags: power-management, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

I recently changed my DE from Unity to XFCE. I really enjoyed it, but the power manager doesn't work. When I try to open it from the settings menu, I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to Xfce Power Manager

Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: 
the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy
blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was
broken.
```

When I try to run it from the command line, it simply does nothing. I found some other solutions where people said to try running xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon (here: [xubuntu 13.10 xfce4-power-manager not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362790/xubuntu-13-10-xfce4-power-manager-not-working)), but then I get the following messages:

```
(xfce4-power-manager:23973): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode


(xfce4-power-manager:23973): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 'CheckAuthorization' failed with Action org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-set-spindown is not registered
```

And then the shell halts until I hit ctrl+c.

Then I read that this is a known bug and the best solution was to downgrade to a previous version of the power manager. I tried using aptitude for this, but it complained that every version I wanted did not exist, even if I was taking the version numbers from the xfce4-power-manager repository. The next thing I tried was to download the package and install it myself. But when I tried to configure, the script told me some libraries were missing, even though they are installed:

```
*** The required package libxfconf-0 was not found on your system.
*** Please install libxfconf-0 (atleast version 4.6.0) or adjust 
*** the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
*** installed the package in a nonstandard prefix so that
*** pkg-config is able to find it.
```

I was told that library is already pre-installed in Ubuntu.

Then I tried using the gnome-power-manager. Even though it is installed, when I try to run it from the command line, it says there is no such program. And it would also not appear in the XFCE settings menu, which I would like.

Answer (score 2):

@Eddie is on the right track in his answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/524316/327339), but I recommend you should instead only:

**Edit the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop` to include the `--no-daemon` addition to the end of the `xfce4-power-manager` command, by doing the following:**

`sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop`
Now arrow down to the bottom of the file and replace this line:
`Exec=xfce4-power-manager`
with this line:
`Exec=xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon`

Use ctrl + x to exit nano, select 'Y' to save, then reboot and the power manager will now work from the settings menu.

*Note: Tested and works at least in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.*

Answer (score 1):

Updating instructions for Xubuntu 14.04.1

**First remove the old launcher**
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop

**Then create a new one....**
Settings Manager / System / Session and Startup
Choose tab Application Autostart

At the bottom click Add and enter the following:

Name:     Xfce Power Manager (for example your name)
   Description:         Power manager    startup
   New command:     xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon

Edited because the askubuntu interface is messing up CR/LF

Answer (score -1):

xfce4-power-manager not started, applet not visible

Delete > Desktop configuration file:

/etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop

Settings Manager / Session and Startup / Startup Applications

Item disabled:

Energy Management (power Management Xfce environment)

New item enabled:

```
      Name:        Xfce Power Manager (for example your name)
      Description: Power manager startup
      New command: xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon
```

http://ubuntuset.url.ph/power_manager.html