# How to get xfce4-power-manager to work in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, power-management, suspend, xfce4-power-manager

I've had nothing but issues with it. On install, everything went fine, but I couldn't modify the lid action, and the suspending was very buggy - sometimes it worked, sometimes not.

Then I found out that `xfce4-power-manager` 1.4.1 fixes the laptop lid issue, so I downloaded a deb and installed it. On first run it went *beautifully*, but on restart, it doesn't work at all. It launches 2 instances on startup, sometimes it even shows that suspend is not available, and lid actions and power actions don't work **at all**.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

If you really really must use Lubuntu instead of changing your default session to XFCE (Xubuntu) [this is the link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1242452) you should visit to find some workarounds for your problem which affects many many users apart from yourself. Though you may think at a first glance that the post deals with some bug specific to Lubuntu 13.10, read ahead on that page to find out that the same bug applies to Lubuntu 14.04 too.

It is the reason I urged you to use the xfce session instead of the lxde session which may be good for desktop computers but it is not that good for laptops.

To be able to use xfce4-power-manager full features in Lubuntu, you need to, and I quote from that page:

> 1. You can go to ---> Menu > Preferences > default application for LXsession > Power Manager > Other > xfce4-power-manager > Apply >
>      Reboot.
>
> HOWEVER, please note that this is not enough and this feature should
>   be loaded by default, just like it used to be.
>
> 2. Another solution is to open Preferences --> Default applications for LXSession, then go to the autostart tab and here change the option
>      "Disable autostarted applications" from the default "config-only" to
>      "no". You may need to change the settings for laptop-mode from "no"to
>      "yes". (settings tab).
>
> Note that you need to disable "network" from Prefereces-->Desktop
>   Session Settings or you will have two nm-applet running at the same
>   time.

There are other unofficial workarounds designed for xfce power manager to work in Lubuntu, and you can check the answers too just to find another good link [to this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129671/how-can-i-workaround-the-xfce4-power-manager-being-broken) where you can find yet another 'working solution' for your problem:

> 3. I had this problem, i unchecked "Power Manager" from "Application Autostart" list in Settings -> Session and Startup and added another
>      application with this command xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon then i
>      have not have this problem yet.

Comment: I do **not** want to do that. Besides, `xfce4-power-manager` is installed by **default** in Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Then you should open Synaptic Package Manager, and use for keyword in the search field this one: **lxde** . Look in the list of results specifically for LXDE package and other LXDE related packages especially those related to power management. It is imperative that you install **lxde** which is not installed by default in Lubuntu to make your system a little bit more stable. Do not forget about the rest of lxde related packages that might prove to be useful for laptop users.

Comment: Taz - this is how to use Xfce (Xubuntu), not how to use xfce4-power-manager in LXDE (Lubuntu)...

Comment: You mean installing lxde and other lxde related packages is no good for Lubuntu? I guess you mean my posted answer to his question (installing xubuntu-desktop), but I plan to delete that one as soon as he actually installs those lxde packages and says that he's happy with power management. Anyway, why does Lubuntu have to use xfce4-power-manager and not some native power manager package for LXDE?

Comment: LXDE **does not have a power manager of it's own**. That's why `xfce4-power-manager` is used.

Comment: Number 1) put me on the right track. On Lubuntu 15.04 what worked for me was: Menu > Preferences > default application for LXsession > Core applications: set **both "Power Manager" and "Lock Screen Manager"** to "xfce4-power-manager

Comment: After all this, the battery icon might still not show in your LXPanel. Then start `xfce4-power-manager-settings` and enable "General → Appearance → Show system tray icon".
Also, if "Menu → Preferences → Default application for LXSession" does not exist in your menu, install `lxsession-default-apps`.