# Lubuntu: Battery indicator missing

Tags: lubuntu

I have an issue similar to [Lubuntu 15.04 lost battery indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614342/lubuntu-15-04-lost-battery-indicator)

But when I go to "Configure Panel > Widgets" there is no battery or power management widget, I can add.

Am I missing a widget package?

Lubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu is now using the LXQt desktop, so details from the different LXDE desktop are not always helpful.   Yes the start of LXQt was the joining of LXDE *devs* & Razor-Qt *devs* creating the new LXQt , but LXQt is not identical to either prior LXDE or Razor-Qt desktops the teams worked on before hand.